# Using Rostopic hz in a ros node

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

Is there a way to get rostopic hz information from within a ros node?  I can't find an API for this.  I did find the source code (https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/master/tools/rostopic/src/rostopic/__init__.py), but I'm not sure how to use this.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48579/using-rostopic-hz-in-a-ros-node/) by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) on ROS Answers with karma: 227 on 2012-11-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I was struggling with this problem because I am not familiar with Python, but it wasn't too hard after reading the rostopic source code for a couple of hours.

I also encountered problems with rostopic hz because I did not have a list of topic names beforehand.  Run the sample ros node below to understand how to retrieve all of this data.  The *myhz()* method will run the ros loop and continuously print out the rate of the *sometopic*, and the *mygraph()* function will print all nodes and edges (with to and from information).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python import roslib; 
    roslib.load_manifest('ssnode') import 
    rospy import roslib 
    import roslib.message
    import rosgraph
    import rostopic 
    from rostopic import ROSTopicHz 
    from rosgraph.impl import graph
    
    def mygraph():
        g = graph.Graph()
        try:
            while 1:
              g.update()
    
              if not g.nn_nodes and not g.srvs:
                  print("empty")
              else:
                  print('\n')
              if g.nn_nodes:
                  print('Nodes:')
                  for n in g.nn_nodes:
                      prefix = n + '|'
                      print('  ' + n + ' :')
                      print('    Inbound:')
                      for k in g.nn_edges.edges_by_end.iterkeys():
                          if k.startswith(prefix):
                              for c in g.nn_edges.edges_by_end[k]:
                                  print('      ' + c.start + ' label = '
+ c.label)
                      print('    Outbound:')
                      for k in g.nn_edges.edges_by_start.iterkeys():
                          if k.startswith(prefix):
                              for c in g.nn_edges.edges_by_start[k]:
                                  print('      ' + c.end + ' label = ' + c.label)
              if g.srvs:
                  print('Services:')
                  for s in g.srvs:
                      print('  ' + s)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
            
             def myhz(topic, window_size=-1, filter_expr=None):
        rospy.loginfo("check if roscore is up")
        while !rospy.is_shutdown():         thegraph();         ros::sleep(10);
            return
        rospy.init_node("myname", anonymous=True)
        rospy.loginfo("registered node name")
        rt = ROSTopicHz(window_size, filter_expr=filter_expr)
        
        # have to subscribe with topic_type
        sub = rospy.Subscriber(topic, rospy.AnyMsg, rt.callback_hz)        
        print("subscribed to [%s]"%topic)
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            rospy.loginfo(rt.times)
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
          mygraph()
          #myhz("sometopic")
        except rospy.ROSInterruptException: pass
```

---

Originally posted by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) with karma: 227 on 2012-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kunaltyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18850/kunaltyagi/) on 2014-07-28**:
What about a C++ program?